# Does forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Sch}\to \mathbf{Top}$ preserves fibre products?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbf{Sch}$ be a category of schemes and let $\mathbf{Top}$ be a category of topological space. We have a forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Sch}\to \mathbf{Top}$. Does this functor preserves fibre products? I don't know whether this is true for affine schemes - for any ring $R$ and $R$-algebras $f:R\to A$ and $g:R\to B$, can we identify $\mathrm{Spec}(A\otimes_{R}B)$ with $\{(\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{q})\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)\times \mathrm{Spec}(B)\,:\,f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) = g^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})\} $?

Comment: No, a standard counter-example is $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C})$ which is a two points topological space (whereas the topological fiber product would obviously be of one point)

Comment: @Roland Thank you! Do you know any criterion for schemes that above statement holds?

Comment: No I don't : it almost never does ! It also fails for $\mathbb{A}^1_k\times_k\mathbb{A}^1_k$... The point is : you should never use the set theoretic fiber product.

Comment: As a side note: You always have a surjection from the scheme-theoretic to the topological fibre product